# Fixed Menu on right hand side

Tags: html, css, reactjs, css-position

I have a webpage with a main div in the center which can be scrolled through vertically.

I want to have a fixed menu that stays stuck onto the right hand side of the page. However, if I use 'position: fixed', the menu overlaps the central div when I resize the page to be smaller than the central div

Full width page:
[image]

Resized page:
[image]

Instead, I want the central div's minimum width to take precedence, and the fixed menu to only appear by scrolling right in this case.

Is it possible for a fixed menu to be position to the right of the central div, instead of stuck to the right side of the browser?

Sorry if this question is unclear, I will gladly answer any uncertainties in the comments

Comment: To answer your question, **yes**, it is possible to achieve that. As for **how** you can achieve that, you'll need to update your question so that it shows your **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have [**tried so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You could add a second div that is the same width as the menu under the menu to push the center div over or you could just size the main div.

Answer (score 0):

Use [This](https://getbootstrap.com/) may be confusing at the start but will be the solution. (make a empty div with the class "col-md-8" and then give the nave bar a surround div with the class of "col-md-4") There are lessons everywhere on this so it shouldn't be hard to pick up. hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

A simple yet efficient approach would be to use flexbox.
Say your central div is 600px and your sidebar is 200px, then you would have the following CSS:

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  // flex defaults to left-to-right row & nowrap, fine in this case
  justify-content: space-between;
  // makes sure your 2 child divs will be pushed left & right
}

.main {
  flex-grow: 1; // makes the main div grow to occupy space if width > 800px
  flex-shrink: 0; // main div never shrinks below its flex-basis size
  flex-basis: 600px;
}

.sidebar {
  flex-grow: 0; // sidebar never grows
  flex-shrink: 0; // and never shrinks
  flex-basis: 200px;
}
```

See [this Codepen](https://codepen.io/Jaxxeh/pen/YEdqpa)

One caveat: flexbox support is wonky on older browsers (IE 10), or flat-out unsupported (IE 9 & below).